# what happened if SESSION is already created and now i'm going to create SESSION of same name in Php

Tags: php, session

I created Login form in my Website and use SESSION.
my code for session is

```
$_SESSION['USERSESSION'] = 'ID'.$value[0];
```

I created SESSION successfully.

Now I am going to create SESSION of same name

```
$_SESSION['USERSESSION'] = 'ID'.$value[0];
```

then what happened ?

Is it **overridden**?

Drop older SESSION and Create new SESSION?
Something else?

Comment: By the way, if you're using sessions properly (with `session_start()` at the beginning of your scripts) then all you're doing is overwriting an array index with the same value it had previously, seeing as sessions are unique to each client.

Comment: Yes, it is overwritten, for clients that are part of that session.

Comment: Most pointless question ever? Is their any other remotely sane behavior it could possibly exhibit?

Comment: thank you @gnat, but some other programmer actually not understand my question, i am new so i am asking hear. 
For helping me they are down my question and says not useful.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that do you mean ?

Comment: http://php.net/_SESSION

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['USERSESSION'] = "value1";  // creates new session `USERSESSION` and assign value1

echo $_SESSION['USERSESSION']; // output : value1


$_SESSION['USERSESSION'] = "value2"; // this will update the session value by value2


echo $_SESSION['USERSESSION']; // output : value2
```

so when ever you assign the value in your session variable it creates the variable and assign the value if not exists. and update if exists.

and you can also check the session variable exists or not like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['USERSESSION']))
{
  // session is set
}
else
{
  // session is not set
}
```

Comment: Update means its add old and new value or replace value1 to value2

Comment: it replace the value1 by value2

Comment: @Albert Mark this answer correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to check that is by reading the value of

```
$_SESSION['USERSESSION']
```

before and after the new value is set.

Comment: exactly, these things shouldnt be asked as questions